# Ramsey's reset test (i.e. Omitted variable bias test) result interpretation

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, goodness-of-fit, bias

I have the Ramsey's reset test result to find whether my regression has any omitted variable bias. It is based on the **logistic regresison model which is a non-linear model**. I have the following result and shall I say I do or do not have omitted variable bias and why?

```
   > resettest(reg_logit,power = 2,type="fitted", data=DATA)

      RESET test

   data:  reg_logit
   RESET = 1.8529, df1 = 1, df2 = 3273, p-value = 0.1735
```

But when I run this ramsey test without any specification on this **same** logistic regression, I get the result as follows:

```
   > resettest(reg_logit)

           RESET test

   data:  reg_logit
   RESET = 19.748, df1 = 2, df2 = 3272, p-value = 2.983e-09
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [lmtest package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/lmtest.pdf), you appear to have five continuous predictors (and maybe some categorical predictors) in your model. We know there are five continuous predictors because your first degrees of freedom is 5, and you can only add squared continuous variables to a model, not squared dummy variables as stated in the manual.

These predictors were squared (`power = 2`) and added to the original model to create a new model. And an *F*-test was used to compare your original model to this new model. The *F*-test was statistically significant suggesting that at least one of the squared continuous predictors is a statistically significant predictor of your outcome.

Your second degrees of freedom is large, so you have a huge sample size, large enough to detect even trivial effects. Even if the relationship is slightly quadratic, you have the power to detect it. Without an explanation of the context, access to the coefficients, some diagnostic plots, one cannot know how problematic your misspecification is.

Note that the RESET test is a test for functional form specification not omitted variable bias (OVB). And OVB might affect some variables while others are not affected. The simplest answer to your question about OVB is yes, it is present. Since you have multiple predictors and individuals were most likely not randomized to have those values of the predictors, there will be OVB.

The package manual and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_RESET_test) do a decent job of explaining the test. Section 6.2.3 of Wooldridge's Econometric analysis of cross section and panel data (2010) clarifies what the RESET test is and misconceptions about it like its (in)ability to test for OVB.

Comment: The data size is large which is 20383. If so what would you say about the omitted variable bias in this case? I also changed the result output as well by having a more simplified example to investigate and figure out the omitted variable problem.

Comment: I already know the dataset is large. There is no definitive test for omitted variable bias. Like I wrote in the reply, unless your participants were randomly assigned to their values on the predictors, you have omitted variable bias.

Comment: If I use the type as "fitted" or "princomp" instead of "regressor", it shows insignificant P-value aligned with my purpose. Can I do in this manner then?

Comment: Selecting what the analysis you want based on how desirable the p-value is makes the p-value meaningless. Better yet, try to understand why the results change in the way they do.

Comment: It's because I am using a logistic regression, a non-linear model, which I think to be the reason. So I think "fitted" works better in this case. If so, shall I presume no omitted variable bias? I just updated my results and the data + model are even different from before.

Comment: I have included both cases from Ramsey test from my same logistic regression in the question window above now.

Comment: How would you recommend to interpret in this case? Shall I say I do or do not have omitted variable bias?

Comment: Errrr, again, there is no test for omitted variable bias. It has nothing to do with logistic regression AFAIK. They are different procedures, so different procedures can result in different answers. I assume one uses fitted values, another PCA reduction of predictors, and last uses raw predictors as predictors of the squared residuals. If you are doing diagnostics, then you should err on the side of caution. If one approach suggests a problem, then do not work to ignore it. I'm not sure what additional advice I can offer beyond be transparent in how your report what you found.

Comment: Ok. Then if I claim that I am using the fitted values procedure for my Ramsey test (if I am correct) and find no omitted variable bias, this statement already confines my situation to the fitted values methodology usage situation. Will this make sense then?

Comment: I now found that "fitted" type for Ramsey test is a generally accepted and widely used methodology compared to the other two, "regressor" and "princomp". The "fitted" one is putting the fitted values of "y" into the regression to check the corresponding coefficient's significance which is generally conducted. Even the Wikipedia shows only this example in the equation if I am correct.

Comment: I have repeatedly severally that there is no test for omitted variable bias. This is a test for functional form specification.

Comment: Then may I know whether the two other tests such as "Rainbow test" and "Harvey-Collier test" are for the same purpose as "Ramsey test"?

Comment: Original reference for Harvey Collier mentions functional form misspecification: A. Harvey & P. Collier (1977), Testing for Functional Misspecification in Regression Analysis. Journal of Econometrics 6, 103–119. I'm guessing the Rainbow is similar. So yes, they are same purpose as Ramsey.

Comment: Thank you. Then if I find omitted variable bias outcome from Ramsey test but no omitted variable bias from one of the two other tests, and if I show off only this favorable test result and claim no omitted variable bias, how would this be supported?